# Regular Expressions - Min & Max with leading zeroes

Tags: regex

I'm trying to validate a Time Frame within an input. I'm trying to be able to enter only the valid months + year. so the input should look like 01-12(.)2018-nnnn

As far as leading zeroes I have a working expression: `^(0[1-9]|1[0-9]).(20[0-3][0-9])$`

However I'm unable to get a combination for both, min/max and leading zeroes to work.

Comment: What do you mean by "leading null"? BTW, `.` matches any char, if you meant to match a `.` char, escape `.`, `^(0[1-9]|1[0-9])\.(20[0-3][0-9])$`, or enclose with square brackets, `^(0[1-9]|1[0-9])[.](20[0-3][0-9])$`.

Comment: What is your exact problem? What do you mean by min/max? Can you paste strings that match OK and strings that don't match yet but should?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are doing this in a regex in the context of some sort of validator where it's not as easy to just parse the date. If not, then I'd just try parsing the date.

But to the Regex answer...

Starting with the month part, whats wrong with this?

Match either 01 - 09

```
0[1-9]
```

or 10 - 12

```
1[0-2]
```

Combine that for:

```
^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])
```

As far as your year, depending on your requirements, it seems you have that part of the regex in hand, so I didn't address it.